# Match one/few group only if are divided by separator

Tags: regex

I need to design a regular expression that can match **only** the names from:

```
Dany and Andy
Steve
Dany and Steve and Andy
Andy and Steve
```

but fails to match the names from:

```
and
and Dany
Steve and Nancy and
```

In other words, I need a regular expression that can Match, either:

1. Name.
2. Two names, if they're separated by separator ' and '.
3. Three names, if each of them is separated from preceding/following with separator ' and '.

What I have so far: https://regex101.com/r/qQ2fY2/1 - it's ugly and I don't like it. I also don't like the fact that I have to type "Kuba" twice (I'd like to put it only once).

How can I accomplish this? (I tried with lookaheads etc. but I guess I can't do it :/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you're trying to match is

```
^\w+(?: and \w+)*$
```

- `\w+` A word followed by
- `" and "` and another word (any number of times)

But it implies another condition: the word can't be `"and"`. You do need a negative lookahead for that to guarantee it's not `"and"`, before matching a word.

```
^(?!and\b)\w+(?: and (?!and\b)\w+)*$
```

- Notice I used a `\b` ([word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) to avoid matching names like "andy".

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qQ2fY2/2)

Comment: YESS!! This is exactly what i wanted! Thanks bro.